# How to get persistent folder permission on Android 11?

Tags: android, scoped-storage

My app scans for text files in certain directories. User can tap a button to add a directory:

```
val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
startActivityForResult(intent, RESULT_CODE_DOCUMENT_TREE)
```

Then I store the URI in the database and use `DocumentsContract` to scan the directory for files and to read them. On application start I load stored URIs and process them the same way to scan for files.

On Android API 28 the stored URIs work fine. On Android API 30 I get a `SecurityException` if I try to access any of them after application restart.

Is there a way to make those permissions persistent on modern Android? Or should I implement a completely different approach?

Comment: `intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_PERSISTABLE_URI_PERMISSION)
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)` Please remove those flags. They do not make sense.

Comment: Handling uries obtained by Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is the same on all Android versions. And you can take persistable uri permission in onAvtivityResult.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The permission granted for the selected directory lasts until the user's device restarts. To preserve the access, you have to take permission from the user. You can asks for permission in your `onActivityResult` method See the example below:

```
val contentResolver = applicationContext.contentResolver

val takeFlags: Int = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION or
        Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION
// Check for the freshest data.
contentResolver.takePersistableUriPermission(uri, takeFlags)
```

[More details here](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#persist-permissions)